# QGIS 3.20 can't load plugin DirectionalSlope, no module named 'gdal', on Windows 10

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I use the standalone version of QGIS 3.20 and I'm trying to install the Plugin DirectionalSlope.

However, when I click the install button this error appears:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gdal' 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.3/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 313, in loadPlugin
    __import__(packageName)
  File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.3/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 799, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:\Users/AWF/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\DirectionalSlope\__init__.py", line 3, in 
    from .DirectionalSlope import DirectionalSlope
  File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.3/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 799, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:\Users/AWF/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\DirectionalSlope\DirectionalSlope.py", line 38, in 
    from .DirectionalSlope_classes import *
  File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.3/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 799, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:\Users/AWF/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\DirectionalSlope\DirectionalSlope_classes.py", line 10, in 
    import gdal
  File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.3/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 799, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gdal'


Python version: 3.9.5 (tags/v3.9.5:0a7dcbd, May  3 2021, 17:27:52) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)] 
QGIS version: 3.20.3-Odense Odense, 495fbaec 

Python Path:
C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.3/apps/qgis/./python
C:/Users/AWF/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python
C:/Users/AWF/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins
C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.3/apps/qgis/./python/plugins
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.20.3\bin\python39.zip
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.3\apps\Python39\DLLs
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.3\apps\Python39\lib
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.20.3\bin
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.3\apps\Python39
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.3\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.3\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\win32
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.3\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.3\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
C:/Users/AWF/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python
```

What is the problem and what can I do to solve it?
Keep in mind that I am new to the program and I don't use Python at all. I just want to use this plugin.

Comment: how did you install qgis? by the standalone installer or by OS4Geo? (sorry, posted this comment accidently as answer)

Comment: I edited my question. I use the standalone version.

Comment: ok - i edited my previously deleted answer. should do the trick!

Answer (score 3):

I, sometimes, encounter that problem right after QGIS installation. Downloading the wheel file from [Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal) generally solves the problem.

In your case,

- Download any `******-cp39‑win_amd64.whl` (maybe the latest version).
- Open OSGeo shell.
- (You may need to uninstall previous GDAL. Use `python -m pip uninstall gdal`
- Use `python -m pip install "FULL_PATH_OF_GDAL_WHL_FILE" -U`

If you still get any error about GDAL, try different version of GDAL on the website.

Comment: I downloaded the GDAL‑3.3.2‑cp39‑cp39‑win_amd64.whl. Do i place it in a particular folder in the OSGeo4W and then install it? Or do I Install it from any path?

Comment: Install it from any path like `python -m pip install c:\users\user\downloads\GDAL‑3.3.2‑cp39‑cp39‑win_amd64.whl -U`

Comment: I forgot `-U` parameter. U means upgrade.

Comment: It shows me this error ERROR: Cannot uninstall 'GDAL'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall. Can I do something to solve it?

Comment: I have no idea at this point?

Comment: Ok, thank you for the effort.

Answer (score 3):

You must report this issue to the plugin author.

This plugin is using an outdated way of importing gdal into his algorithms.

```
import gdal
```

is deprecated for many years.

The author must upgrade the plugin to

```
from osgeo import gdal
```

If you go edit `C:\Users/AWF/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\DirectionalSlope\DirectionalSlope_classes.py` line 10, you can do it yourself.
But you may have other imports in another area of the code. And your update will be overwritten by a plugin update, so better to report it to plugin author.

Comment: You are right. I edited line 10 and then an error returned for line 11 because there is no module 'gdalconst'. So i may have to contact the editor. But the strange thing is that this plugin has worked perfectly for a coworker without doing anything. I dont know why.

Comment: Which QGIS version for your coworker ? Which OS ? The important thing is the version of GDAL provided by your QGIS. In the help/about menu, you will find it. I think it's GDAL/OGR 3.1. Can you say thisanswer solve your problem ?

Answer (score 2):

Use the network installer (recommended for normal users). this will ensure all the dependencies will be installed - gdal is one of those.
To make sure of it use "advanced installation". In the step where you can actually choose the packets to install, search for "gdal" - this is how it looks at my machine:
[image]

Comment: I uninstalled the standalone version, and i used the network installer but it didnt solved the problem. Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: edited the answer - have you verified that gdal is installed according to the network installer tool?

Comment: How to you do that? From the OSGeo4W shell? This shows me that i have the GDAL 3.3.1 Version but it still doesnt work.

Comment: I did the advanced setup like you said but still no result.

Comment: in QGIS, go to Settings->Options-> Processing->Providers-> GDAL   is the box checked here?

Comment: Yes, the GDAL box is checked.

Answer (score 0):

Should be just the GDAL imports style.
Fixed in https://gitlab.com/mauroalberti/directionalslope/-/tags/v1.3.2 and submitted new version to the QGIS plugin repository for approval.

Comment: Thanks to etrimaille and Koumkou for pointing to the issue.