# Module Not Found Error: No module named 'gdal' when installing RS&GIS, a QGIS Plugin

Tags: qgis, gdal, qgis-plugins

So I'm trying to create a Land Surface Temperature (LST) using the RS&GIS plugin in QGIS. When finished installing the RS&GIS plugin, I get an error massage says

```
Couldn't load plugin 'NITK_RS-GIS_17' due to an error when calling its classFactory() method

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gdal'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\QGIS/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 335, in _startPlugin
    plugins[packageName] = package.classFactory(iface)
  File "C:\Users/HP/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\NITK_RS-GIS_17\__init__.py", line 34, in classFactory
    from .RSGIS_M import RSGIS
  File "D:\QGIS/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 799, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:\Users/HP/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\NITK_RS-GIS_17\RSGIS_M.py", line 57, in 
    import gdal
  File "D:\QGIS/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 799, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gdal'


Python version: 3.9.5 (tags/v3.9.5:0a7dcbd, May  3 2021, 17:27:52) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)] 
QGIS version: 3.20.3-Odense Odense, 495fbaec 

Python Path:
D:/QGIS/apps/qgis/./python
C:/Users/HP/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python
C:/Users/HP/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins
D:/QGIS/apps/qgis/./python/plugins
D:\QGIS\bin\python39.zip
D:\QGIS\apps\Python39\DLLs
D:\QGIS\apps\Python39\lib
D:\QGIS\bin
D:\QGIS\apps\Python39
D:\QGIS\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages
D:\QGIS\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\win32
D:\QGIS\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
D:\QGIS\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
C:/Users/HP/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python
```

Has anyone had an experience like this before? I'm new to QGIS and I don't know how to solve this kind of error.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds very similiar to this topic: [QGIS 3.20 can't load plugin DirectionalSlope, no module named 'gdal', on Windows 10](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/413708/qgis-3-20-cant-load-plugin-directionalslope-no-module-named-gdal-on-windows/413712?noredirect=1#comment672775_413712)

you can try the suggested solutions (network install, make sure gdal is correctly installed) but it seems to be a problem of the plugin itself - so contacting the developer and making them aware of the problem would be probably the best!

Answer (score 0):

It's a [bug](https://github.com/PrathamGitHub/NITK_RS-GIS_17/issues/15) that has been fixed but the new version has not been uploaded to the QGIS plugins repo.

Uninstall the plugin, download the [master repo from github](https://github.com/PrathamGitHub/NITK_RS-GIS_17/archive/refs/heads/master.zip) as a zip file and [install from the zip](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins.html#the-install-from-zip-tab).