# QGIS - gdal installed but missing when trying to load plugin

Tags: qgis, gdal, qgis-plugins

I'm trying to use the plugin RS&GIS on my work machine (after successfully having used it on my private machine), but the plugin won't load and shows the following error: `Couldn't load plugin 'NITK_RS-GIS_17' due to an error when calling its classFactory() method. ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gdal'`. Below is the full error message. However, if I start up the osGeo4W shell and try `pip install gdal` it tells me that the requirement is already satisfied: `gdal in c:\osgeo4w\apps\python39\lib\site-packages (3.3.1)`.

What can I do to make it work?

```
Couldn't load plugin 'NITK_RS-GIS_17' due to an error when calling its classFactory() method 

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gdal' 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\OSGeo4W/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 335, in _startPlugin
    plugins[packageName] = package.classFactory(iface)
  File "C:\Users/Francesco Paganini/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\NITK_RS-GIS_17\__init__.py", line 34, in classFactory
    from .RSGIS_M import RSGIS
  File "C:\OSGeo4W/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 799, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:\Users/Francesco Paganini/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\NITK_RS-GIS_17\RSGIS_M.py", line 57, in 
    import gdal
  File "C:\OSGeo4W/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 799, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gdal'


Python version: 3.9.5 (tags/v3.9.5:0a7dcbd, May  3 2021, 17:27:52) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)] 
QGIS version: 3.20.2-Odense Odense, 9f59a156 

Python Path:
C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis/./python
C:/Users/Francesco Paganini/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python
C:/Users/Francesco Paganini/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins
C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis/./python/plugins
C:\OSGeo4W\bin\python39.zip
C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39\DLLs
C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39\lib
C:\OSGeo4W\bin
C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39
C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages
C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\win32
C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
C:/Users/Francesco Paganini/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python
C:\Users\Francesco Paganini\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\DigitizingTools\tools
C:\Users\Francesco Paganini\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\DigitizingTools
```

Comment: check here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/413708/qgis-3-20-cant-load-plugin-directionalslope-no-module-named-gdal-on-windows/413712?noredirect=1#comment672775_413712

Comment: did you run `py3_env`?

Comment: @Ian Turton: Thanks for your answer, no I have not. at what point in the process would I need to run that command?

Comment: before trying to use `python`

Comment: I'm not exactly using python directly, it is the plugin that uses it without me having much influence on it. Do you mean that before loading the plugin I would need to run the 'py3_env' command in the qgis-python-console? Sorry if I'm slow to understand your input.